How to integrate $\int \frac{x^{2}+7(\sqrt[m]{x^{m}})+6}{\sqrt[m]{x^{m}}+1}dx$?
Q)How to integrate $\int \frac{x^{2}+7(\sqrt[m]{x^{m}})+6}{\sqrt[m]{x^{m}}+1}dx$ ? Here, $m=2n$ and $n=$ natural number.
First of all my approach:
Let $$I=\int \frac{x^{2}+7(\sqrt[m]{x^{m}})+6}{\sqrt[m]{x^{m}}+1}dx$$
$1)$ When $\sqrt[m]{x^{m}}=|x|=+x$, then:
$$I=\int\frac{x^{2}+7x+6}{x+1}dx$$
$$\implies I=\int\frac{(x+6)(x+1)}{(x+1)}dx$$
$$\implies I=\int(x+6)dx$$
$$\implies I=\frac{x^{2}}{2}+6x+C$$
$2)$ When $\sqrt[m]{x^{m}}=|x|=-x$, then:
$$I=\int\frac{x^{2}-7x+6}{(1-x)}dx$$
$$\implies I=\int\frac{(x-6)(x-1)}{(1-x)}dx$$
$$\implies I=\int(6-x)dx$$
$$\implies I=6x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+C_1$$
But my doubt is how to solve the integral in a single case by taking both the cases together? I am facing problem in solving this integral by taking both the cases together in a single case and then integrating.
Generally in my class XIITh book, this types of questions are solved by taking only the case of $\sqrt[m]{x^{m}}=|x|=+x$. But I can't understand that why in the book the $2^{nd}$ case that is $\sqrt[m]{x^{m}}=|x|=-x$ is ignored.

You may factorise the numerator as $x^2 + 7\lvert x\rvert + 6 = \left(\lvert x\rvert+1\right) \left(\lvert x\rvert+6\right)$, then after cancelling the $\int \lvert x\rvert ~ dx$ may be represented in a single case using the sign function.

You seem to have answered your own question. You found an unusual textbook error. It seems to me to be both an error in pedagogy in the sense that the notation of the question is left unsimplified in a way that most instructors don't care about and also an error in the answer. If a distinction is made elsewhere in the text between odd and even powers then maybe the question writer originally intended $m=2n+1$. With an odd value of $m$, the textbook answer would be correct.

It's not entirely clear what is meant by $\sqrt[m]{x^m}$.  This notation is unusual because if the intent is that $\sqrt[m]{x^m} = |x|$, presumably, the question should have simply used the absolute value notation.  If the intent is that $\sqrt[m]{x^m} = x$, again, the question should have been written that way.
If we assume the former--i.e. the intent is $\sqrt[m]{x^m} = |x|$--then we may write for all real $x$
$$\frac{x^2 + 7|x| + 6}{|x| + 1} = \frac{|x|^2 + 7|x| + 6}{|x| + 1} = \frac{(|x| + 1)(|x| + 6)}{|x| + 1} = |x| + 6.$$  Cancellation is allowed because $|x| + 1 > 0$.
Then integration proceeds as usual:
$$\int |x| + 6 \, dx = \frac{x|x|}{2} + 6x + C = x\left(\frac{|x|}{2} + 6 \right) + C.$$
